# Mandatory /obligatory drug effects

Tags: alternatives

Medications are not always effective, so I'm trying to write that "their effects are not mandatory or obligatory, " but I'm not sure if either of these terms are right.

For example: *Aspirin effect on headache is not obligatory.* There are several ways to rewrite this, but I'm strictly interested in the potentially more appropriate word...

Comment: Either 'certain' or 'guaranteed' are better than 'mandatory' or 'obligatory'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either 'certain' or 'guaranteed' are better than 'mandatory' or 'obligatory'. – Ross Murray